# How do I get HP LaserJet 2100 PCL6 printer working with Win7 x64?

Tags: hp, printing, windows-7

I have a Debian server with cups installed to serve up my HP LaserJet 2100 PCL6 to all machines connected to the network.  I can print test pages from cups, but cannot seem to find the correct driver for Win7 x64.  I have been to HP site and downloaded their recommended drivers, and choose them (via "Have Disk") when adding the printer but when I print a test page it prints a page saying "protocol not supported". Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  Have to use the ***HP LaserJet 2200 Series PCL 5*** driver included with win 7.  The 2100 series drivers provided by HP did not work for me.